# Cargar Select en base a la seleccion de otro Select

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Estoy tratando de realizar un select dependiendo de la seleccion de otro select (es decir en base a la seleccion de una vacuna mostrar la cantidad de dosis de esa vacuna seleccionada )utilizando js puro pero no logro poder hacerlo. A continuacion les comparto el codigo html y js. Estoy realizando un proyecto en mvc con c# y el back lo estoy realizando con html, java script y css.

Les comparto el codigo html

```html
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>Vacunas:</td>
                <td colspan=3>
                    <select name="vacuna" id="vacuna" onchange="cargarVacunas();">
                        <option value="">Seleccione una Vacuna...</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dosis:</td>
                <td colspan=3>
                    <select name="Dosis" id="cantidad">
                        <option value="">Seleccione una Dosis...</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

A continuacion les comparto el codigo en js

```js
function cargarVacunas() {
    var array = ["Sputnik", "Cansino", "Covishield", "Sinopharm", "Bcg"];
    array.sort();
    addOptions("vacuna", array);
}

function addOptions(domElement, array) {
    var selector = document.getElementsByName(domElement)[0];
    for (vacuna in array) {
        var opcion = document.createElement("option");
        opcion.text = array[vacuna];
        opcion.value = array[vacuna].toLowerCase()
        selector.add(opcion);
    }
}

function cargarCantidades() {

   
    var listaCantidades = {
        sputnik: ["1º dosis", "2º dosis", "3º dosis", "4º dosis", "5º dosis"],
        cansino: ["1º dosis", "2º dosis", "3º dosis", "4º dosis", "5º dosis"],
        covishield: ["1º dosis", "2º dosis", "3º dosis", "4º dosis", "5º dosis"],
        sinopharm: ["1º dosis", "2º dosis", "3º dosis", "4º dosis", "5º dosis"],
        bcg: ["1º dosis"],
    }
    var vacunas = document.getElementById('vacuna')
    var cantidades = document.getElementById('cantidad')
    
    var vacunaSeleccionada = vacunas.value.toLowerCase()

    cantidades.innerHTML = '<option value="">Seleccione una dosis...</option>'

    if (vacunaSeleccionada !== '') {
        listaMaterias
        vacunaSeleccionada = listaCantidades[vacunaSeleccionada]
   
        if (!!vacunaSeleccionada.length) vacunaSeleccionada.sort()

        vacunaSeleccionada.forEach(function (cantidad) {
            let opcion = document.createElement('option')
            opcion.value = cantidad
            opcion.text = cantidad
            cantidades.add(opcion)
        });
    }

}

cargarVacunas();
```

[image: Les dejo las imagenes de manera que puedan ver que al ejecutarse no me muestra las dosis de la vacuna seleccionada]
[image: ademas empiezan a duplicarse los datos en el primer select]

Les agradecería mucho su ayuda. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código funciona, nada más necesitas modificar el onchange de tu select de vacunas para que corra **cargarCantidades** en lugar de **cargarVacunas**, y borrar **listaMaterias** en cuanto entra a tu if

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Jose me funciono. Te agradezco mucho. Ahora me surgio otro inconveniente. Resulta que agregué mas vacunas al array y al ejecutar el programa no me muestra las vacunas agregadas. La verdad muy raro.

Comment: quizá no lo agregaste bien, deberías de revisar bien tu código